# express and socket.io authentication -- how do I retrieve the cookie/session info?

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, cookies, socket.io

Preface:   I'm new to node.js, express, socket.io and all of that. I realize my code is kinda messy and needs to be separated out into modules, etc -- but I've not done that yet because I was trying to get the authentication part working first. I have searched all over stackoverflow and other sites. I've found some promising examples, but I've just not been able to make it work.

I followed a couple of tutorials to create my express app which allows a user to register, login, and view their details. I also followed a tutorial which helped me make a basic socket.io chat. What I'm trying to do is combine them and have the user log in and then be redirected to the chat app. The problem I have is that when I redirect them, I have no way to know "who they are" on the socket.io side of things. Currently I've got it set up so you have to enter your name to chat -- I would like it to grab the info from the session and use that instead.

Currently when a user logs in, it does set a cookie (I can view it in the console). So I know the cookie is there. It also sets the info into the MongoStore. I've verified that as well with db.collection.find().

Here's the code that I have so far. If any of the experts out there could help me find a way to pass the session info over to socket.io, I would very much appreciate it!

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var path = require ('path');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var session = require('express-session');
var moment = require('moment');
var now = moment().format('L');
var http = require('http');



var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

UserSchema = new Schema({
    //id: ObjectId,

    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,    
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        uniqueCaseInsensitive:true
    },
    password: String,
    email: {
        type:String,
         unique: true,
        uniqueCaseInsensitive:true
    },
    accountType: String,
    accountStatus: String,
    acctActivation:{ 
        type:String,
    unique:true
},
joinDate: String

});
UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator,{ message: 'Error,  {PATH} {VALUE} has already been registered.\r' });
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var app = express();
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.locals.pretty = true;

//connect to mongo
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myUserDb');

//create server

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
var client = require('socket.io')(server);
console.log('listening on port 3000');


//middleware
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret!',
    resave:false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
    stringify:true,
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/sid2'

  })

}));

app.use(csrf());

app.use(function(req,res,next){ // check to see if user already has a session, if so, query mongodb and update the user object
    if(req.session && req.session.user){
        User.findOne({email: req.session.user.email}, function(err, user){
            if(user){
                req.user = user;
                delete req.user.password; // remove password field from session
                req.session.user = req.user;
                res.locals.user = req.user;
            }
            next();
        });
    }else{
        next();
    }
});

function requireLogin(req,res,next){ //  check to see if user is logged in, if not, boot em
    if(!req.user){
        res.redirect('/login');
    }else{
        next();
    }
};
function requireAdmin(req,res,next){ // check to see if accountType = Developer (or admin later) - if not, send them to dashboard
    if(req.user.accountType !== 'Developer'){
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }else{
        next();
    }
}; 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.user){
          res.render('dashboard.ejs');
    }else{
          res.render('index.ejs');
    }

});

app.get('/register', function(req,res){    
    res.render('register.ejs', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
    error:false});
});

app.post('/register', function(req,res){        
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));

    var user = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: hash,
        email: req.body.email,
        accountType: 'Standard',
        accountStatus: 'Active',        
        joinDate: now
    });

    user.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);

            res.render('register.ejs', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
                error: err});

    }else{
       req.session.user = user; 
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    }); 

});

app.get('/login', function(req,res){

    res.render('login.ejs', {
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),error:false});
});


app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    User.findOne({username: {$regex: new RegExp('^' + req.body.username, 'i')}}, function(err, user){
        if(!user){

            res.render('login.ejs', {error: 'Invalid username or password combination.',
             csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
        }else{
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){

                req.session.user = user;

                res.redirect('/chat');
            }else{

                res.render('login.ejs', {error: 'Invalid username or password combination.',
                 csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
            }
        }
    });
});

app.get('/dashboard', requireLogin, function(req,res){   
       res.render('dashboard.ejs');
});
app.get('/chat', requireLogin, function(req,res){   
       res.render('chat.ejs');
});
app.get('/admin', requireLogin, requireAdmin, function(req,res){   //required logged in AND admin status
  // var userlist = User.find({});

   User.find({},{},function(err,docs){

       res.render('admin.ejs',{ "userlist": docs

       });

   }) ;



      // res.render('admin.ejs');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req,res){
    req.session.reset();
    res.redirect('/');
});

mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/chat', function(err,db){
    if(err) throw err; 

client.on('connection', function(socket){

    var col = db.collection('messages');
    sendStatus = function(s){
      socket.emit('status', s);  
    };

    //emit all messages (shows old room data)
    col.find().limit(100).sort({_id: 1}).toArray(function(err, res){ 
        if(err) throw err;
        socket.emit('output',res);

    });

    //wait for input
    socket.on('input', function(data){
      var name = data.name,
      message = data.message,
      whitespacePattern = /^\s*$/;

      if(whitespacePattern.test(name) || whitespacePattern.test(message)){
          sendStatus('Name and message is required.');
      }else{
          col.insert({name: name, message: message}, function(){
              //emit latest message to all clients 

              client.emit('output', [data]);

         sendStatus({
             message: "Message sent",
             clear: true
         });

          });
      }

    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've finally figured it out. I used express-session to set the cookie, and then a module called [express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) to get it over to socket.io.

From there, I was able to use:

`var data = socket.handshake.session;
console.log(data.user.username);`

to retrieve the values I needed.  All of these days searching and it was a very simple solution. I guess I just needed some sleep!